# Uploading images to S3 bucket from browser via NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload images from the browser to Amazon S3, and the code below sends some sort of blob to Amazon S3 just fine, I can't read the resulting file in a browser. It doesn't seem to know it's an image file.

I send it to NodeJS from the browser:

```
let myReader=new FileReader();
myReader.onloadend=(e)=>{ app.ws.send(myReader.result); }
myReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

In NodeJS I send it to S3:

```
const s3=new AWS.S3();
const params= { Bucket:<bucketName>, Key:fileName, Body:imgData, ACL:"public-read", ContentEncoding:'base64' };
s3.putObject(params, (err, data)=>{
    if (err) throw err; 
});
```

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: The image seems to be there in some form, but when I click on the link, in AWS, it downloads instead of displaying like images if upload using their console. When I click on the image on my desktop, it says it  desn;t support the file. Here's a link: https://etalimages.s3.amazonaws.com/3/BiilPic+14L.JPG

Answer (score 0):

Check AWS S3 guide,
This doc contains the logic needed to upload image from browser to S3 bucket

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Comment: I have been looking at it, but I'm using putObject here, not Managed upload. The docs were not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to modify the base64 image data coming in and explicitly set the ContentType:

```
const s3=new AWS.S3();
const type = imgData.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];
imgData= new Buffer.from(imgData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
let params = { Bucket:<bucketName>, Key:fileName, Body:imgData, 
    ACL:"public-read", ContentType:"image."+type, ContentEncoding: 'base64' };

s3.upload(params, (err, data)=>{
    if (err) throw err;
    ... Do something ... 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for sharing of this, Bill. I have the same issue with `PutObjectCommand`. Applied your solution and worked!

```js
const client = new S3Client({});
const fileData = usr.fileData;
const fileName = usr.fileName;
const base64Buffer = new Buffer.from(fileData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
const command = new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: 'test',
  Key: `avatar/${fileName}`,
  Body: base64Buffer,
  ContentType: 'image/png',
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  //ACL: 'public-read', // Set appropriate ACL based on your requirements
});
    
try {
  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log('Image uploaded successfully:');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error uploading image:', err);
  socket.emit('uploadError', { error: 'Failed to upload image' });
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the posters question or and answer to your own question?